# Ajax Request for JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I try to request the following `JSON` Data:

```
 {"status":"success","id":8,"title":"Test","content":"dies ist test 12"}
```

With this Ajax Request:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://www.XXX.de/?apikey=XXX&search=test',
type: "GET",
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(data){
$('#content_test').append(data.content);
 },
 error: function(data){
 //
 }
});
```

It is not working. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you want to set the dataType to "jsonp". The json you show is not wrapped in jsonp.

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Comment: @Maddin please tell us the full error message and stack trace if there is one.

Comment: The response is: "syntax error json parse unexpected end of data at line 1 of column 1 of the json data" I think there is something wrong with the json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution::

To get the data it is necessary to have a correct callback like this in the PHP file of WP:

```
$callback = $_GET['callback'];
$response = json_encode( $return );

if ( ! empty ($callback)){
echo $callback . '(' . $response . ')';
} else {
echo $response;
}

die;
```

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
 url: 'http://www.XXX.de/?apikey=XXX&search=test&callback=?',
 type: "GET",
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data){
 $('#content_test').append(data.content);
  },
  error: function(data){
  //
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example on how to use jsonp](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.XXX.de/?apikey=XXX&search=test',
    type: 'GET',        
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: '$callback',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#content_test').append(data.content);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Also open your development tool (Ctrl + Shift + J) and check if you have any errors in your console output.

Comment: Not working. I created the JSON data by myself. Is that correct?

Comment: The console says: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Comment: Can you check in your console if you are getting data back? You might get data back but it's not properly formatted. If you getting data back, please post what you get back.

Comment: The console says successful response. When I try to change from JSONP to JSON it works in Safari but in Firefox I get an Cross Domain error.

Comment: Please change it to jsonp and since you are getting successful response, can you show what data you are getting back? You might have an issue with data that you are getting back.

Comment: Sorry I did wrong. The response is: "syntax error json parse unexpected end of data at line 1 of column 1 of the json data"

Comment: Looks like you are having issue with json that comes back from the server. Can you verify that you are getting data back from the server? And can you share the data that you are getting back?

Comment: yes thats the strange thing. with an other JSON on the same server it is working.

Comment: Can you share your working and not working JSON data?

Comment: sure, working: {"status":"ok","page":{"id":2,"type":"page","slug":"beispiel-seite","url":"http:\/\/XXX.de\/beispiel-seite\/","status":"publish","title":"Beispiel-Seite","title_plain":"Beispiel-Seite","content":"\r\nicke bins\r\n\n","excerpt":"","date":"2015-09-03 13:34:56","modified":"2015-09-16 13:20:44","categories":[],"tags":[],"author":{"id":1,"slug":"admin","name":"admin","first_name":"","last_name":"","nickname":"admin","url":"","description":""},"comments":[],"attachments":[],"comment_count":0,"comment_status":"open","custom_fields":{}}} here i work with data.page.content

Comment: not working: {"status":"success","id":8,"title":"Test","content":"dies ist testus 12"}

Comment: In your success function, instead of calling $('#content_test').append(data.content); could you please call console.log(data); and share what you get?

Comment: Since you are using different language you might encode your data before you sending it over the wire on the server side. Are you encoding that data?

Comment: No i didn't encode something. I made it with Wordpress and wp_send_json.

Comment: Thats the logging: Object { readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), done: f.Callbacks/p.add(), fail: f.Callbacks/p.add(), progress: f.Callbacks/p.add(), state: .Deferred/h.state(), 12 weitere… }

Comment: It works now with this code:  $.ajax({
url: 'http://XXX.de/?apikey=XXX&search=test',
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',

success: function(data){
  $('#content_test').append(data.content);
 },
 error: function(data){
  console.log(data); 
 }
});

But why it works now with POST?

Comment: wp_send_json is a right way of doing. I'm looking for log of the data that you  are getting back from the server. I don't see your data. Can you share it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89817/discussion-between-maddin-and-vlad-bezden).